# What prevents a replay attack in XCM?

Tags: xcm, xcmp, cumulus

I've been looking into Cumulus SDK's parachain and `XCM` handling functions in `XcmpQueue` to handle XCM protocol functions such as `send_xcm()`. It seems by default, messages are not signed when sent.

If this is the case, what prevents a malicious person from replaying an XCM message to perform a replay attack?

Answer (score 3):

Replay attacks only work in setups where messages are received via an un-trusted delivery mechanism - hence the need for signing; to authenticate the sender.

For `XCMP`, the delivery channel is already trusted. Only the sender can inject messages into the channel, no one else. The relay chain guarantees this.

Now if you are *solely* looking at XCM as a language (and not the DotSama use for XCMP/VMP/HRMP) then yes - replay is possible. But so is in any other language without build-in authentication, like English.